# Serial Over IP, windows-linux

Tags: windows, linux, internet, serial-port, serial

I need to have a serial port "shared" over the Internet (may or may not be using a VPN). At one end is a Windows box, and at the other is a Linux box, which has the serial port

The Linux box has no GUI and is controlled over SSH only.

I would just run the program I wanted over SSH,
but the program I want to use (br@y's terminal) is only available for Windows. I am in the process of authoring my own program to replace the use of Br@y's. However, I am doubtful of completing it by Friday when we have a product prototype demonstration.

I'm looking for a freeware (preferably open source) serial over IP program (I think).

Comment: so to clarify: you need a Windows terminal program that can access serial over IP, and you need a linux "connector" program that will supply the IP-to-serial endpoint.  why not use SSH and run a terminal program on the linux box (minicom, etc)?

Comment: Minicom does not meet my needs, it's really very much designed from modem communcation.
It does not allow typed streams to be transmitted (esp not when typedin hex or deciaml)
I am authoring my own program do do this, as i mentioned in the question

Comment: ah, ok, i've seen your other questions.  but my comment really was trying to clarify: is this accurate?  'you need a Windows terminal program that can access serial over IP, and you need a linux "connector" program that will supply the IP-to-serial endpoint.'

Comment: yeah, I think that what I want.
I've actaully now finished authoring my program (though it's untested and i have limmited dev time before the demo).
SO this discuassion becomes more academic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found two neat sourceforge projects called [Telnet Com Port Control Daemon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/telnetcpcd/) and [Serial Over IP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/serialoverip/) which seem to be coded for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the words "serial over IP".
I have a machine shop with 10 CNC machines that have serial ports.

We use a lava-link boxes to accomplish sending over any of several computers via ethernet to the lava-link boxes, which has serial ports coming out the other side of it which are hooked to the each machine.

Each lava-link has an IP address for each serial port.  I send to an Adept robot the same way too.

It may take more than a couple of days to get a lava-link box in time for your demo (and it could be that I do not understand the question and this is not a solution at all).

It runs ssh and telnet and a few other protocols too.
And we talk to the machines in both windows and Linux.

Would a hardware solution like this get serial data to your robot?

Link:
http://lavalink.com/products/ether-serial-device-servers/