# ATEN USB to Serial driver on Windows 8 - using Linux driver?

Tags: linux, windows-8, usb, drivers, rs232

I'd like to use an [ATEN UC232A USB to serial converter](http://www.aten.com/Mobility-&-USB/USB-Converters/USB-to-Serial-Converter~UC232A.html) on my computer with Windows 8. I downloaded the appropriate driver which seems to work but after a while produces a blue screen because of the error DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (Wdf01000.sys). On some website it was recommended to use the windows 7 driver, which gave the same problem, even when I installed the driver in compatibility mode for windows 7.

Then I plugged the converter into my Ubuntu Server 14.04, which works without any problem. I didn't need to install anything.

However, I really need to use this device on my computer with windows 8. Is there a possibility to run a linux driver on windows, for example?

Comment: You cannot use a Linux driver within Windows for the same reason you cannot use windows drivers within Linux the existence of the Win32 library.  Contact the manufacture for assistance with this problem it's likely their driver is the cause.  There are multiple versions of the product which one do you have?

Comment: You can't use a Linux driver on Windows - but you can cheat: Why not have a virtualized minimal Linux system running, with the USB device redirected to it? Ofcourse no Windows driver should be installed.

Comment: @EugenRieck yes, this would be a possibility, but the software I want to use in the end (http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en546974) doesn't come with a linux version. I could build it myself since the source is available, but it's rather complicated. There's no possibility to have this virtual system make windows think it has an extra serial port, or something like this? To share the port in the virtual machine with windows?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not aware of different versions?

Comment: That's what I ment! User serial over IP or something similar to share the serial port from the Linux side to the Windows side.

Comment: @EugenRieck thank you very much, I didn't know that was a possibility. Just to check, is http://superuser.com/q/109396/187676 what I need?

Comment: Might be -  I normally use http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/ for the server and http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html for the windows client

Comment: @EugenRieck thank you, I got this working, but the client creates a _Virtual_ serial port, not a normal port (if I look in the device manager), and the software that needs the serial port doesn't see this virtual port. Is there a way to make it look like a real port?

Comment: On the website you linked to it even talks about a new revision that supports android.  So there are multiple revisions of the hardware

Comment: Every serial-over-ip port is a "virtual" serial port inside the OS: This is also true for Bluetooth SPP and friends. From the application's POV there is no difference to a "real" or "physical" port, so it looks as if the application you use actively discriminates against networked serial ports.

Comment: @EugenRieck hm, okay, that's a pity. I'm now using a virtualbox running windows xp (for which there is a working driver), with a shared folder so that the application can access the necessary files. It works, though it's not a great solution. What shall I do with this question now? It doesn't seem so likely to me that it will help future visitors in this state.

Comment: I think you need to just leave it this way. Completely OT: Working USB-RS232 adapters are something like $5,- on eBay ...